# I need help identifying what stars these are

Tags: star

I took these photos in the early morning. I’m in North America for a general location. I’m just curious on what they are as I can’t tell.[I edited one so only the stars show, if that’s any help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhCwy.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

These stars are the constellations of Orion and the two dogs.

Orion is clearly identifiable by the "belt" of three stars.  Following the belt towards the left you come to "Sirius" in the constellation of the dog.(Sirius is the brightest star in the sky) and in to top left is Procyon, the lesser dog.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of experience, you'll be able to immediately identify Orion.

Mostly because I'm fascinated by computer vision, I uploaded your processed image (the darker one, showing only the stars) to [astrometry.net](https://astrometry.net), and it came up with this:

[image: description]

http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/5335519#annotated

You might like to try it with the unprocessed image. Click `use` -> `web` and upload your image.

Comment: I feel this is the better general solution as it gives a way forward for any field and produces an image with a World Coordinate System that allows star lookups for any field.

Comment: +1 have you seen [How can I recognize the stars in a .fit image and get information about their magnitude and intensity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47428/7982)

Comment: @uhoh yeah I saw that one. I've been playing around with photutils from https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection.html but I haven't looked at how it handles a different fits file.